# Rickshaw misinteprets the datetime

Tags: datetime, d3.js, rickshaw

I am using the Rickshaw javascript library to show represent some graphical values, following the model from [here](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/lines.html). The data to be drawn is provided through an Ajax call, for example:

> [{"color":"#65A1CC","data":[{"x":1383906402000,"y"
>   :22.31},{"x":1383906428000,"y":22.38},{"x":1383906452000,"y":22.31},{"x":1383906477000,"y":22.38},{"x":1383906502000,"y":22.38},{"x":1383906527000,"y":22.38},{"
>   x":1383906552000,"y":22.31},{"x":1383906577000,"y":22.31}],"name":"Sensor 1"},{"color":"#CC9065","data":[{"x":1383906402000,"y":22.38},{"x":1383906427000,"y":22
>   .38},{"x":1383906452000,"y":22.38},{"x":1383906477000,"y":22.38},{"x":1383906502000,"y":22.38},{"x":1383906527000,"y":22.38},{"x":1383906552000,"y":22.38},{"x":
>   1383906577000,"y":22.38}],"name":"Sensor 2"}]

The long values given here are data time between Fri Nov 08 13:26:42 FET 2013 and Fri Nov 08 13:29:37 FET 2013.

However, when hovering over the resulted graph, the dates shown for various values appear like "Sat Apr. 03", as in the image below. I do not understand why: if in javascript I iterate over the data, the javascript Date object show November time, not April.

[image]

The code is:

```
<div id="chart_container">
<div id="chart" style="background-color: white;"></div>
<div id="legend_container">
    <div id="smoother" title="Smoothing"></div>
    <div id="legend"></div>
</div>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

```
$.ajax({                        
         type : "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         url : "/myApp/someURL",
         data: { pack:selectedpack} 
      }
     ).done(function(data) {
        showDashboard(data);
    }); 

function showDashboard(data) {
    $("#charts").show();
    $("#chart").empty();
    $("#legend").empty();

    var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
        element: document.getElementById("chart"),
        width: 1000 - 130,
        height: 400,
        renderer: 'line',
        series: data
    });

    graph.render();

    var slider = new Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider({
        graph: graph,
        element: $('#slider')
    });

    var hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({
        graph: graph
    });

    var legend = new Rickshaw.Graph.Legend({
        graph: graph,
        element: document.getElementById('legend')

    });

    var shelving = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle({
        graph: graph,
        legend: legend
    });

    var axes = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time({
        graph: graph
    });
    axes.render();
}
```

The following js files are included: `jquery-ui.min.js, d3.v2.js, rickshaw.js, Rickshaw.Class.js, Rickshaw.Compat.ClassList.js, Rickshaw.Graph.js, Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.js, Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.Area.js, Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.Line.js, Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.Bar.js, Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.ScatterPlot.js, Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider.js, Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail.js, Rickshaw.Graph.Annotate.js, Rickshaw.Graph.Legend.js, Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time.js, Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle.js, Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Order.js, Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Highlight.js, Rickshaw.Graph.Smoother.js, Rickshaw.Graph.Unstacker.js, Rickshaw.Fixtures.Time.js, Rickshaw.Fixtures.Time.Local.js, Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.js, Rickshaw.Fixtures.RandomData.js, Rickshaw.Fixtures.Color.js, Rickshaw.Color.Palette.js, Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y.js`

What should I do to obtain the November ... time instead of April?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass in seconds, not milliseconds, so you should divide your time data by `1000`. For example, instead of `1383906452000` you need to have `1383906452`.

If it's not possible to return the time values in seconds from the server side, on the client side, you might use the following before calling `showDashboard(data)`:

```
$(data).each(function (e, i) {
    $(i.data).each(function (f, j) {
        j.x = j.x / 1000;
    });
});
```